# MS SQL Server 2005 Express x86 - its port is unreachable - help

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc, database-connection, connection-pooling

I have just installed the MS SQL Server 2005 Express and, of course, I am trying to connect it with my test app but the thing is ... for some reason I cannot connect it
I have already checked its port with the CP "netstat -an" but the outcoming list does not contain any 1433 port at all :( The SQL service is running I could check it with the OS Services but its port is unavailable :( I have installed MS SQL Server 2005 Express Management Studio but for some reason it connected the MS SQL successfuly :(

So the question is... How to install the MS SQL to be able connecting it with a client (Java) app?

For more information:
OS: Windows XP x86 SP3
MS SQL Server 2005 Express

Any useful comments are appreciated

Thanks

Comment: i'm working with netbeans with java and sql server 2005 so you can check this URL http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/netbeans-69-java-microsoft-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Start>All Programs>Microsoft SQL Server ????>Configuration Tools>SQL Server Configuration Manager

In the tree on the left, Select the nodes listed below and make sure that the Status of TCP/IP is "enabled".  In truth I'm not sure if they both have to be enabled or just one.

```
SQL Server Configuration Manager>SQL Server Network Configuration>Protocols for MSSQLSERVER

SQL Server Configuration Manager>SQL Native Client 10.0>Client Protocols
```

If they aren't enabled, simply right click on them and click "Enable".
I'm not positive that this will fix you're problem, because it's been a while since I ran into 'my' problem, but it sounds like the same thing.

Comment: I have already checked the TCP/IP enability with the Configuration Tools and it is enabled :( Maybe there is something else? I tried to check its port with netstat -ab and thing I could find are much strange... As first I can see the "the sqlserver" port is getting changed time after time and it is enything (1078 or 1348 or...) but 1433 but whaen I try to connect it I get error which says I must check the server is running and has a port etc... ? to so what can it be?

Comment: And I just thought... I have win xp sp3 so maybe I need to upgrade the sqlserver to some service pack too?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the following MSDN How To article:

[How to: Configure a Server to Listen on a Specific TCP Port (SQL Server Configuration Manager)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)