# SQLServer authentication exception by jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

i'm trying to connect to a newly installed SQLServer instance by my java application using jdbc.
When i try to open a connection the server return this error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'.
```

Error Stack trace:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'. at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerE‌​xception.java:197) at    
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
```

I've already enabled "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" option.
I also tried to connect to the database server with SquirreL but i had the same problem, but with SQL Server Management Studio i can connect to the db.

I have a SQLServer 2008 R2 express, jdk 6u41 and sqljdbc4.jar JDBC connectors.
I've tried the same application in an environment with SQLServer 2008 R2 express, jdk 6u33 and sqljdbc4.jar JDBC connectors and it work fine.

Are there some SQL server configuration that i need to modify?

Comment: Where is the error stack trace ?

Comment: This is the first part of stack trace:  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'.
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)   Do you need the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441158/an-attempt-to-login-using-sql-authentication-failed#8441182

Comment: What is your connection URL?

Comment: Are you sure you are providing the correct password? And why is your application using `sa` in the first place? That should only be used by the DBA.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have configured the SQL Server in Windows Authentication mode on the time of installation but, changing the settings in the program would not change it from Windows Authentication mode.

Can you do one thing? Remove the SQL Server 2008 and all related programs from your machine and install a fresh copy, this time with SQL Server Authentication. It will work...

Comment: I configured it with "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" at installation time, but when i chose this option i configured two user, "sa" and the windows current logged user. It can have anything to do with my problem?