# JDBC connection to SQL Server: login failed for user x

Tags: java, eclipse, sql-server-2008, database-connection, connection-string

I am trying to set a JDBC connection to Sql Server 2008. I have created a database in Sql Server with this information:

```
CREATE LOGIN xtest WITH PASSWORD = 'berenjenas7(((';  
GO  
CREATE USER samxtest FOR LOGIN xtest;  
GO  
GRANT SELECT TO samxtest;
GO  
GRANT INSERT TO samxtest;
GO  
GRANT UPDATE TO samxtest;
GO  
GRANT DELETE TO samxtest;
GO
```

I installed the JDBC driver from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774
and **I used the connectURL class from this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342339.aspx
in order to test the connection**.

I left the default port 1433 in the code. The following picture should be proof that this is really the port:
[image]
And of course I changed the connection string to:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=XTest;user=samxtest;password=berenjenas7(((";
```

I don't understand what is wrong?
The error I get is:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user
>   'samxtest'. ClientConnectionId:2344af.....    at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
>     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   connectURL.main(connectURL.java:18)

Comment: Does CREATE USER samxtest FOR LOGIN xtest; is same as set Login Enabled ?

Comment: @Sam please review this , possibly [replicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403636/connecting-sql-server-2008-to-java-login-failed-for-user-error)

Comment: I don't know if they are the same. But I did a test and also tried this: ALTER LOGIN xtest ENABLE; ALTER LOGIN xtest WITH PASSWORD = 'abcdefghijkl' and then replaced the connection string by String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=XTest;user=xtest;password=abcde‌​ghijkl"; but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Misread:

Make sure that Authentication Mode of the SQL server  “Mixed Mode (Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication)”.

Run following script to change the authentication

```
LOGIN xtest ENABLE

ALTER LOGIN samxtest WITH PASSWORD = 'password'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks Stranger! I don't see Mixed mode at all, I currently have 2 options when opening Sql Server Management Studio: Windows Authentication AND Sql Server Authentication, and I select Windows Authentication each time, so I login with server name = "local". Should I change this to Mixed, and how if it doesn't show up?

Comment: Also, samxtest (if you check my initial question) is not a LOGIN, it's a USER. The login is called xtest. I tried what you say with LOGIN xtest (this is detailed in my first comment to swingNoobie). Not working though.

Comment: please verify this by checking the properties of the server and then SECURITY, it should be in 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode'

Comment: Horray! I just did that and it now works! Thanks very much, Stranger! You're a hero.

Comment: **As a summary**: I don't know why I couldn't connect with the USER I created, so **I assigned LOGIN a PASSWORD as stated in Stranger's answer** and that coupled with the fact **I switched to SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode** as advised above did the trick!