# Receiving SQLException "Login failed for user" connecting to SQL Server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string, sqlexception

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 via Java.

1. I've added `sqljdbc4.jar` to my project's library.
2. No username and password is set for database accessing the database (Windows Authentication).
3. The 1433 port is Listening, but I still receive this exception:

> SQL Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:085d5df3-ad69-49e1-ba32-b2b990c16a69

Relevant code:

```
public class DataBases 
{

    private  Connection link;
    private  java.sql.Statement  stmt;
    public    ResultSet rs;

    public DataBases() 
    {  
        try 
        {    
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DB;";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cE)
        {
            System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want windows authentication you need to add the option  `integratedSecurity=true` to your JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DB;integratedSecurity=true
```

You also need `sqljdbc_auth.dll` (beware of 32/64 bit) in your Windows system path or in a directory defined through `java.library.path`

For details see the driver's manual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx#Connectingintegrated

Comment: For where to download `sqljdbc_auth.dll`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19116116/2646526).

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue when I tried to connect to Microsoft SQL server from Java. I used [`jTDS`](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) driver instead of regular `SQLJdbdc` Driver.

```
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"); 
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DB;integratedSecurity=true";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Its because of the wrong format of the ConnectionUrl. You are missing username and password in the ConnectionUrl.

```
String ConnectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DB","username","password");"
```

I hope it works well!!!

Answer (score 0):

This post my help:
[jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user for any user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769171/jdbc-sqlserverexception-login-failed-for-user-for-any-user)

You need the `integratedSecurity=true` flag and make sure the server properties are indeed set to 'Windows Authentication Mode' under Security.