# dll missing in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, authentication, dll, jdbc

I am currently working with SQL in Java.
Recently I got this error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
```

This happens when I add the parameter `integratedSecurity=true;` in the connection String.
The error message clearly says that sqljdbc_auth.dll is missing, so I tried to put the dll in the same path as I keep sqljdbc4.jar.

However, this doesn't work, so I wanted to know how I actually can add this dll to my build path? Is there a special way to do it?

Comment: afaik you need add path to dll into Windows property PATH

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright guys, I found it out!
I didn't really need to change the java.library.path but the "Native library location" of sqljdbc.jar

This is the best answer I could find:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/958074/2000342

It works now, thanks for the support!

Answer (score 44):

keep `sqljdbc_auth.dll` in your windows/system32 folder and it will work.Download sqljdbc driver from this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774) Unzip it and you will find `sqljdbc_auth.dll`.Now keep the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` inside system32 folder and run your program

Answer (score 12):

For easy fix follow these steps:

1. goto: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url#Connectingintegrated
2. Download the JDBC file and extract to your preferred location
3. open the auth folder matching your OS x64 or x86
4. copy sqljdbc_auth.dll file
5. paste in: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_version\bin

restart either eclipse or netbeans

Comment: Alternatively, copying only to C:\Windows\System32 folder also works.

Comment: Note that __sqljdbc_auth.dll__ has been rename to __mssql-jdbc_auth-x.x.x.x86.dll__ starting from version 8 of the JDBC driver. So you need to copy and then rename the dll.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set a -D system property called `java.library.path` that points at the directory containing the `sqljdbc_auth.dll`.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?
I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 4):

Set java.library.path to a directory containing this DLL which Java uses to find native libraries. Specify -D switch on the command line

java -Djava.library.path=C:\Java\native\libs YourProgram

C:\Java\native\libs should contain sqljdbc_auth.dll

Look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse) if you are using Eclipse or at [this blog](http://blog.cedarsoft.com/2010/11/setting-java-library-path-programmatically/) if you want to set programatically.

Comment: Thank you! The description on the top wasn't very clear, I consider you to edit it a little bit.
In return, your link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse helped me a lot! This is where I found the  answer to my problem

Answer (score 2):

If its the case of the dll file missing you can download the dll file from this link 
http://en.osdn.jp/projects/sfnet_dose-grok/downloads/sqljdbc_auth.dll/

else you need to provide the username and password of the db you are trying to connect, and make the authentication as false

Answer (score 2):

In my case after spending many days on this issues a gentleman help on this issue below is the solution and it worked for me.
**Issue:**
While trying to connect SqlServer DB with Service account authentication using spring boot it throws below exception.

*com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:ab942951-31f6-44bf-90aa-7ac4cec2e206
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2392) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar!/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sqljdbc_auth (Not found in java.library.path)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1462) ~[na:2.9 (04-02-2020)]*
**Solution: Use JTDS driver with the following steps**

1. Use JTDS driver insteadof sqlserver driver.

   - 

   ## ----------------- Dedicated Pick Update properties PROD using JTDS ----------------

   ```
   datasource.dedicatedpicup.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://YourSqlServer:PortNo/DatabaseName;instance=InstanceName;domain=DomainName
   datasource.dedicatedpicup.jdbcUrl=${datasource.dedicatedpicup.url}
   datasource.dedicatedpicup.username=$da-XYZ
   datasource.dedicatedpicup.password=ENC(XYZ)
   datasource.dedicatedpicup.driver-class-name=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
   ```

- 

2. Remove Hikari in configuration properties.

   *#datasource.dedicatedpicup.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
   #datasource.dedicatedpicup.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5*
3. Add sqljdbc4 dependency.

   com.microsoft.sqlserver
   sqljdbc4
   4.0
4. Add Tomcatjdbc dependency.

   org.apache.tomcat
   tomcat-jdbc
5. Exclude HikariCP from spring-boot-starter-jdbc dependency.

   org.springframework.boot
       spring-boot-starter-jdbc
       
           
               com.zaxxer
               HikariCP

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your DLL is in the classpath.

One such way to do so is to put the path to the DLL in PATH environment variable.

Other option is to add it to the VM arguments in the variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, like this:

`java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/my/dll -cp /my/classpath/goes/here MainClass`

Answer (score 0):

Friends I had the same problem because of the different bit version 
Make sure following point
* Your jdk bit 64 or 32 
* Your Path for sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64 or x86   this directory depend on your jdk bit
* sqljdbc_auth.dll select this file based on your bit x64 or x86 and put this in system32 folder and it will works for me

Answer (score 0):

The sqljdbc_auth.dll is within the sqljdbc_x.x folder you install to retrieve the sqljdbcxx.jar file in the auth folder.  Create a lib folder at the base of your scala project and move sqljdbc_auth.dll into this folder.  This makes sure that you are getting the correct file, e.g. 64 bit or 32 bit that matches your sqljdbcxx.jar file.