# Jmeter Database Testing

Tags: jmeter

For my application we connect to Two database. One is Application database which a a normal SQL server database and the second one is SSAS cubes ( SQL Server Analysis Services ).

In order to test MDX query Load on Jmeter I made JDBC Connection confuguration and JDBC Requet

JDBC Connection confuguration = jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SRV-05:1433;DatabaseName=ETPAnalytics1
JDBC Requet =select * from users

I am facing issues.....The above connections works fine and get a proper Response however when i try to connect to Cubes of Analysis Services.It gives error "Login failed for user 'SRV-05\Administrator'.
I have tried different Login Id.
For your information.Our Analysis services is windows authenticated.So When I leave the user id and password.It tries to Login with Local machines domain ID.

I have tried different Drivers as well.....Kindly help..

[Error for connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWv4o.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Windows authentication in your test you need to amend database url to have

1. [integratedsecurity=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229691/difference-between-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-security-sspi) bit in your JDBC URL
2. [sqljdbc_auth.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277001/dll-missing-in-jdbc) somewhere in [java.library.path](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/)
3. use of the machine, you're running JMeter on need to have relevant permissions on the cube

   ```
   jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instanceName=instance1;integratedSecurity=true;<more properties as required>;
   ```

sqljdbc_auth.dll is a part of the [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx), choose the appropriate dll as per your operating system architecture.

It also worth checking out [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) guide to have better understanding on how you can work with JDBC Request sampler results.