# How to add sqljdbc_auth.dll to eclipse class path

Tags: java, sql-server, classpath, mssql-jdbc

I have an error my program doesn't found the sqljdbc_auth.dll. How to add it to the class path ? Could any one give a little more details please ?

Comment: try to search a bit, and be more specific
See this link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277001/dll-missing-in-jdbc

Comment: I have read many solutions , only one worked for me , is to place the .dll in the jre_version/bin folder ,but the problem with this solution is when there is a upgrade , i need to move the .dll again .