# Sql exception com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception: login failed for user ''. Clientconnectionid:073b35b2-0e56-460d-8353-9de2b2d0ecff

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I am Using Windows Authentication (Please kept in mind).

As there is no user name and password.

then

why the following code gives me error?

```
public class Conection
{
public static void main(String a[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    try
    {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\MALIKUSMANNAWAZ:1433;databaseName=ali";   
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("connection created");
        Statement st=conn.createStatement();
        String sql="select * from Login_System";
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println("Name: "+rs.getString(1));
            //System.out.println("Address : "+rs.getString(2));
        }
        if(st!=null)
        st.close();
        if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle)
    {
        System.out.println("Sql exception "+sqle);
    }
}
}
```

Please Kept in mind that my PC Name is:

```
MALIKUSMANNAWAZ
```

using:

```
Windows Authentication
```

Database Name:

```
ali
```

IDE:

```
SQL Server 2012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `;integratedSecurity=true` to your connection string.  While you are not required to submit credentials if you are using windows authentication you still have to tell your connection to use your windows logon.

here is microsoft's article on jdbc connection strings. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Now the error is:                                      Jun 27, 2016 12:35:47 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277001/dll-missing-in-jdbc is an exact duplicate of ;integrated security failed to load....  That answer says you need to change the path of sqlddbc.jar and then links to the accepted answer on this post of changing the path. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse/958074#958074

Comment: Now Done it, as the answer is given below.

Answer (score 0):

Completed As Given:

```
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\MALIKUSMANNAWAZ:1433;databaseName=ali","sa","dbase");

        System.out.println("connection created");

        Statement st=conn.createStatement();

        String sql="select * from Login_System";

        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
```