# UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

Tags: java, sql-server, maven

I'm using Maven to install Spring Boot project that uses SQLServer, but Tests phase fails: 'SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication', caused by 'UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path'. It happens only while using Maven, not while compiling the project in eclipse.
I use maven-surefire-plugin.

I copied sqljdbc_auth windows\sysWOW64 and to Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin and some more libraries, but it doesn't seems to be the solution.

Comment: try copy that file to `Java\jdkversion\bin` according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277001/dll-missing-in-jdbc

Comment: Ok, now it works!, the solution was to add this configuration line inside maven-surefire-plugin:                                                                                             
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <argLine>-Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 7.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_7.0\enu\auth\x64"</argLine>
         </configuration>
            </plugin>

Comment: That is the directory where sqljdbc_auth is found!

Comment: Thanks @Qingfei Yuan !!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not using [type-4 JDBC](https://www.javatpoint.com/jdbc-driver) for SQLServer which require platform dependent library loading. I suggest you switch to [type-4 SQLSERVER driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) so that you only need depends on driver jar. Should be good solution.

Comment: I'm using JDBC for SQLServer, it works, but doesn't works with tests in Maven.

Comment: how do you configure JDBC for your test?

Comment: This is included in my application.properites: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=CouponsSystemDB;integratedSecurity=true;
spring.datasource.driver-class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
#spring.datasource.username=root

#spring.datasource.password=

#spring.jpa.properties.*
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

#spring.jpa.hibernate.*
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update