# Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a Javafx program that I'm trying to connect to a SQL Database through Windows Authentication mode. I have put the mssql-jdbc_auth-12.6.1.x64.dll file in the - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin.  I have set the  -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin" within Intellij run configurations. The connection file looks like the following:

```
try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://NEMGLASQL001\\SQLSERVER:1433;database=gaitData; integratedSecurity = true; authenticationScheme=NativeAuthentication;");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The code that I'm running to show all results in a specific table is as following:

```
    try{
        DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection cn1 = db.getDBConnection();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM DiagnosisCode";
        Statement statement = cn1.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

The errors showing are -

```
Mar 19, 2024 9:39:48 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SenncomSDK\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\sh0184\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\sh0184\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\sh0184\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.3\bin;;C:\Users\sh0184\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Users\sh0184\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2\bin;;.
```

Does the sqlauth dll need to go somewhere else?

Comment: The error message says that it is looking for a file named `sqljdbc_auth.dll`.  But in your question, you said you copied `mssql-jdbc_auth-12.6.1.x64.dll` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin`.  The file it is looking for has a different filename from the file you copied.

Comment: I've changed the tags to hopefully increase your question's visibility with people more likely able to help. Note that while you may be creating a JavaFX application this error is not related to JavaFX, so I removed JavaFX-specific tags.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277001/dll-missing-in-jdbc     -- i found this stackoverflow answer. It looks like the dll does need to be renamed.