# Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:38ff695a-da7f-466a-901e-c6a70a1d9bdf

Tags: sql, sql-server, maven, jdbc, liquibase

I am attempting to use Liquibase to deploy changes to SQL Server.

I have set up the sqljdbc jar file and placed it in my local maven repository. I then attempt to use the liquibase-maven-plugin to run the changes placed in the changelog for the given connection URL.

Here is what my connection URL is: `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=Jenkins_BuildServices;password=hi;`

I already created the login on my localhost and gave it sysadmin privileges. I also have made sure that the properties -> security is set to both SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode. Any ideas as to why the url being passed in is giving me back this error and not reading it from the URL?

Comment: This may be a [duplicate question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945075/receiving-sqlexception-login-failed-for-user-connecting-to-sql-server-2008) Looks like you need to pass in `integratedSecurity=true` to your JDBC URL.

Comment: That is for Windows Authentication though, is there a way to just use SQL Server Authentication that is what I am trying to use when getting the error

Comment: What does your `pom.xml` - especially the configuration for liquibase maven look like? Are you using property files? Did you go by the [documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/index.html) of the liquibase maven plugin?

Comment: <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <changeLogFile>database.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
          <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
          <defaultSchemaName>liquibase</defaultSchemaName>
          <url>${DatabaseURL}</url>
          <contexts>local</contexts>
          <logging>debug</logging><promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>