# SQL Server log in failing from Java DriverManager.getConnection(), working from Python with pymssql.connect()

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jtds, pymssql, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to use `DriverManager.getConnection()` to connect to a SQL Server db from a Java application, but I keep getting "Login failed for user" errors with it. I've tried using both `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` and `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` to connect, but both keep hitting the issue.

Here's the code I'm using to connect:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");  
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVERADDRESS:1433;DatabaseName=DBNAME;user=USER;password=PASS");
```

I know that account has access to that DB, as I've connected to it before from a Python application using `pymssql.connect(SERVERADDRESS, USER, PASS, DBNAME)` with the same server/DB/creds.

From [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945075/receiving-sqlexception-login-failed-for-user-connecting-to-sql-server-2008), I eventually managed to get it working using windows authentication with my personal account, but I still can't get it to work using our service account. Does anyone have any insight into why the Python app can connect but the Java one can't?

Comment: When you connect from the Python app are you specifying the service account username as `DOMAINNAME\USERNAME`? In other words, is the service account a Windows account, as opposed to a "SQL Server Authentication" login name?

Comment: I am, it's passing in `domain\\svc_account`. I'm doing the same in the connection string in Java. So the connection string is `"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVERADDRESS:1433;DatabaseName=DBNAME;user=domain\\svc_account;password=PASS"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pymssql is built on top of FreeTDS. Both FreeTDS and jTDS support an older Windows authentication scheme named NTLM, while current versions of Microsoft's JDBC Driver for SQL Server (mssql-jdbc) no longer support that authentication mechanism.

So, given that you've confirmed that pymssql can connect, you should be able to connect from your Java app as Windows user `MYDOMAIN\username` using jTDS like so:

```java
String myUid = "username", myPwd = "mypassword";
String connUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.123:1433/databasename;DOMAIN=MYDOMAIN";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connUrl, myUid, myPwd);
```

Comment: Bless you kind soul, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

To find out the reason of "Login failed for user" one should go to SQL Server **error log**.

The next row to `18456 error` will give you the reason.

The most probably reason of failure in your case is that the server is configurated to use `Windows Authentication only`