# SqlServer: Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I've written a very simple JDBC login test program. And after all kinds of problems I've almost got it working. Almost, just can't seem to get past this problem:

> SQLServerException: Login failed for user xxxxx

I created a simple database PersonInfo then I created user user1 password1 (SQL authentication). And after trying everything was unable to connect to the database.

I am using SqlServer2008 on Win 7, I've got the latest JDBC driver from Microsoft.

My code is:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class hell {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
Connection conn=  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=PersonInfo;user=Sohaib;password=0000;");


System.out.println("connected");
       }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here's the Exception

```
Exception: Unable to get connect
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'Sohaib'.
and all other supporting errors.
```

Comment: There could be a number of things that could cause this - take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403636/connecting-sql-server-2008-to-java-login-failed-for-user-error?rq=1 and see if any of the suggestions help you out.

Comment: If you created "user1 password1" in the database you should of course use "user1 password1" in your connection string. Does the user1 have enough rights? Another hint: Did you try to connect user1 in the sql server management studio?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and I fixed it by adding my windows username to SQL and then to my server, here is how I did:

First, create a new login with your Windows username:
[image]

Click Search, then type your name in the box and click check names.
[image]

Then add your that user to the server:

Right click on the  Server >  Permissions > Search > Browse > Select your user
(You will notice that now the user you created is available in the list)

[image]

I hope it helps ;-)

Answer (score 207):

Is your SQL Server in 'mixed mode authentication' ?  This is necessary to login with a SQL server account instead of a Windows login.

You can verify this by checking the properties of the server and then SECURITY, it should be in 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode'

This problem occurs if the user tries to log in with credentials that cannot be validated. This problem can occur in the following scenarios:

**Scenario 1:** The login may be a SQL Server login but the server only accepts Windows Authentication.

**Scenario 2:** You are trying to connect by using SQL Server Authentication but the login used does not exist on SQL Server.

**Scenario 3:** The login may use Windows Authentication but the login is an unrecognized Windows principal. An unrecognized Windows principal means that Windows can't verify the login. This might be because the Windows login is from an untrusted domain.

It's also possible the user put in incorrect information.

**http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332**

Comment: Don't forget to restart the SQL Server service (not the SSMS)

Comment: For anyone wonder where to find the authentication bit (solution 1): (MS SQL Server Management Studio): `Right-click on Sever (inside Object Explorer Dialog) > Properties > Security > Server Authentication`. Next, restart by `Right-clicking on Server > Restart`.

Answer (score 114):

In my case, I had to activate the option "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode", follow all steps below:

1 - Right-click on your server
[image]

2 - Go to option Security

3 - Check the option "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"

4 - Click on the Ok button
[image]

5 - Restart your SQL Express Service ("Windows Key" on the keyboard and write "Services", and then Enter key)
[image]

After that, I could log in with user and password

Comment: Well understandable

Comment: I ALWAYS forget to do this when setting up a new dev machine, must have found at this post 5 times by now :D

Comment: Restarting the server worked for me (i had already done the previous steps before), thanks

Comment: you can restart mssql from SSSM

Comment: wow this is still valid solution for me

Answer (score 5):

We got this error when reusing the ConnectionString from EntityFramework connection. We have Username and Password in the connection string but didn't specify

> "Persist Security Info=True".

Thus, the credentials were removed from the connection string after establishing the connection (so we reused an incomplete connection string). Of course, we always have to think twice when using this setting, but in this particular case, it was ok.

Comment: Saved my bacon! I was struggling with this error message and this fixed it for me.  Note that this is on asp.net (not asp.net core) connection string in web.config.

Comment: @GregGum yes, was asp.net for me too.

Comment: helped me when I upgraded from .net core 3.1 to .net 6

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error message when trying to connect to my SQL DB in Azure (using sql-cli). The simple solution was to escape the password with single quotes like this:

```
mssql -s server.database.windows.net -u user@server -p 'your_password' -d your_db -e
```

Comment: An oldie but a goodie. I thought I'd explain why for good measure. Try `echo "dollar$yay"` on your command line. For example, on BASH, this outputs "dollar" because `$yay` is interpreted as a variable, which in this case I haven't set. If I instead try `echo 'dollar$yay' `, the output is `dollar$yay` as we probably expected. TLDR: if your password contains a character like `$` which may be interpreted between "double-quotes", try this experiment, and either escape the special character like `echo "dollar\$yay"`, which renders `dollar$yay` in BASH, or use single quotes if available.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that account is not locked out in user properties "Status" tab

Answer (score 1):

I have also caught the same issue,But don't worry the solution is so simple

We need to understand the basic terms first that this error “**Login Failed for User (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)**” means you entered invalid credentials when logging into SQL Server with specific **server authentication** type.
[image]

Where I have Selected the option of **Windows Authentication** mode in Server Authentication

and In my ConnectionString in appsettings.json file has the following connection string:

```
Server=DESKTOP-PK4BJF5;Database=lms;Trusted_Connection=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=true
```

In which the "**trusted-connection**" is a parameter used in database connection strings to specify the type of authentication to be used when connecting to a database server.

When "trusted-connection" is set to "true" or "SSPI" (Security Support Provider Interface), it means that the connection will use Windows Authentication to authenticate the user. This means that the credentials of the currently logged-in Windows user will be used to connect to the database server. This type of authentication is also sometimes referred to as "integrated security".

When "trusted-connection" is set to "false", it means that the connection will use SQL Server Authentication to authenticate the user. This means that the connection string will contain a user ID and password that are used to connect to the database server.

**I am Updating the Connection String line and just write SSPI instead of /false**

```
"Server=DESKTOP-PK4BJF5;Database=lms;Trusted_Connection=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=true",
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Can not connect to the SQL Server. The original error is: Login failed for user 'username'.` error, port requirements on MSSQL server side need to be fulfilled.

There are other ports beyond default port 1433 needed to be configured on Windows Firewall.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25147251/1608670

Answer (score 0):

We solved our Linux/php hook to SQL Server problem by creating a new login account with SQL Server authentication instead of Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case any one else is using creating test users with their automation....

We had this same error and it was because we had recreated the user (as part of the test process). This caused the underlying SID to change which meant that SQL couldn't properly authenticate the user.

We fixed it by adding a drop login command to our testing scripts to ensure that a previously created user (with the same user name) was no longer present on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same problem. I've used Entity Framework and thought that DB will be created automatically. Please make sure your DB exists and has a correct name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have configured as below in my springboot application.properties file then I am able to connect to the sqlserver database using service account:

```
url=jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER_NAME:PORT_NUMBER;databaseName=DATABASE_NAME;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;multiSubnetFailover=true;integratedSecurity=true
    jdbcUrl=${url}
    username=YourDomain\\$SERVICE-ACCOUNT-USER-NAME
    password=
    hikari.connection-timeout=60000
    hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
    driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this connection string

```
Server=ServerName;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method: add `Trusted_Connection=True;` to your connection string.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Windows Authentication, make sure to log-in to Windows at least once with that user.

Answer (score -2):

Previously I was using the Windows Authentication without problems, then occurred me the error below.

> "Failed to generate SSPI context."

Witch I resolve by changing my connection string from

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Database=[DB_NAME];Trusted_Connection=True;
```

to

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Database=[DB_NAME];Trusted_Connection=False;
```

Then the next error occurred me

> "Login failed for user ''."

To solve this problem I used the `sa` user. Access the `sa` user to update de password if you need (on the SQL server `Security > Logins > sa (right click) > Properties > General)`) and then update the connection string to..

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Database=[DB_NAME];User Id=sa;Password=[YOUR_PASSWORD]
```

You can use another user of your choice.

Comment: Disabling Windows Authentication and logging in as a sysadmin is a **very** bad idea. Fix the real error instead of disabling security