# ODBC Error in SQLDisconnect following Microsoft Tutorial

Tags: sql-server, machine-learning, odbc, jupyter-notebook, revoscalepy

I am currently trying SQL Server's new Machine Learning Services for Python by following Microsoft's [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mlserver/2018/07/10/run-r-and-python-remotely-in-sql-server-from-jupyter-notebooks-or-any-ide/). I am on a Win10 x64, SQL Server 2017 x64, using *Jyputer Notebook* and *RevoScalepy*.

Connection to the database is not a problem, as verified through *pyodbc*:

```
import pyodbc

sql_conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
query = 'SELECT * from dbo.iris_data'
df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)

df.head(5)
```

[Output from pyodbc](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mlserver/2018/07/10/run-r-and-python-remotely-in-sql-server-from-jupyter-notebooks-or-any-ide/)

However, when trying to running a function on SQL Server through RevoScalePy's *rx_exec()* I receive the error message:

```
RuntimeError: revoscalepy function failed.
====== username ( process 0 ) has started run at 2019-02-18 09:25:58 W. Europe Standard Time ======

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'username'.



[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Connection not open



ODBC Error in SQLDisconnect

Could not open data source.
ImportDataSource function failed. Please see the console output for more information.
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372606/sqlserver-login-failed-for-user

Comment: The way i read this answer is that there is either the server does not support Windows login, or my connection string is invalid, but if that was the case, would I be able to connect to the database through Pyodbc, using Windows Login with the same connection string? Is there some difference between connection through Pyodbc and RevoscalePy?

Edit: I am also able to connect to the database through SQL Server Management Studio using Windows Authentication.