# How to connect Netbeans to Microsoft Sql Server?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, netbeans

I have a problem connecting my SQL server database to Netbeans. The error I get is *"Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Registration using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:3ca0fbd4-70fa-4780-95fe-52b759f6a37f)"*

What I did:

1. Opened Sql Server and Created a database and used Windows Authentication since Im doing all this on my personal device.
2. I downloaded the jdbc zip folder and unzipped it to access the mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar file.
3. I opened Netbeans and went to my project. I then added the mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar file under my libraries.
4. I then went to "Services", right-clicked on Database and created a new connection. I created a new driver and added the mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar file to it.
5. I filled in all the necessary details but I still get an error when testing the connection.

Please note: I enabled my TCP/IP beforehand. I also ensured that my software is updated. I also tried adding "integratedSecurity=true;" and "integratedsecurity=false" but the results are still the same. I also tried removing the port number and using "localhost" as my Host. I have added pictures to show the steps I went through.

The file I used:
[image: The file I used]

SQL Server login:
[image: SQL Server login]

The error I get after everything:
[image: The error I get after everything]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SqlServer: Login failed for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372606/sqlserver-login-failed-for-user)

Comment: To be able to use integrated security, you must have the necessary DLL file on your path.

Comment: So you're trying to use Windows Authentication? Have you tried removing the values in User Name and Password fields, and adding `;integratedSecurity=true` to your JDBC URL?

Comment: Yes I tried this.

Comment: Do you have the necessary DDL on your path?

Comment: Just took it from the "auth" folder and copied it to the Java/bin folder but that didnt solve it. Is there any other way to do it besides this way?