# Can't connect to mssql server with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, aws-lambda, odbc, pyodbc

I have used the following code:

```
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    server="SERVER NAME",
    database="DATABASE NAME",
    user=sql_username,
    password=sql_password,
    port=1433,
    driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    )
```

And the error i get is:

```
[ERROR] InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sqladmin'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Goal: have an aws lambda function which will run sql queries in my MSSQL database.

Set up: i have all the relevant pyodbc dependencies / drivers for my lambda which i got from here: https://github.com/kuharan/Lambda-Layers

Points to note:

- I want to use SQL server authentication (Not windows authentication).
- I have seen posts about where people used "Trused_Connection=yes" which is what results in windows authentication being used. I have not used that here.
- I have tried with "Trused_Connection=no" and get the same error
- I have tried driver='{SQL Server}' but this does not work as the driver can't be found and i can't find where to download this driver to add to my lambda zip file
- The Username and Password are correct.
- I have used the RDS endpoint as the server name

Comment: `The Username and Password are correct.` <- that's not what the error message seems to indicate. Let me ask this: does the password contain any special characters like `$` or `?`? They probably need to be escaped for whatever the heck "aws lambda" uses to send the password across...

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372606/sqlserver-login-failed-for-user) solve your problem?

Comment: Look in the SQL Server error log.  It will contain the exact reason for the failure.

Comment: `sqladmin` is not a standard account name on SQL Server. Is it one that you created? Can you use that account name and password to login from standard tools like SSMS?

Comment: @AaronBertrand please could you submit your comment as an answer? Escaping the special characters did the trick for this error! Still having connection issues but that's a whole new error

Answer (score -1):

> The Username and Password are correct.

That may be true, but keep in mind that how a password gets passed through may require escaping. Characters like `$` can be problematic, as I mention [here](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/vs-code-mac-sql-linux-docker) (this isn’t AWS but similar concept).